# Save TPM initialization key, re-initialize, then restore

Tags: windows-10, tpm

From what I've read, when you initialize a TPM chip it creates a random derived key (derived from its implicit root key). Other users will then set PCRs (i.e. UEFI, bootloader, etc), and eventually BitLocker will seal those values to generate its key.

I have to send my computer in for maintenance. I'd like to save off the initialized key (which will be encrypted by *this* chip's key, which is fine), re-initialize the TPM (so the warranty servicers *cannot* access the data), then, when I get it back, load the original key back into it (so BitLocker and other services work again).

How do I do this?

(Note: if they replace the MOBO and I get a computer back with a different TPM, then obviously I can't restore it. That's irritating, but that's fine - I can rebuild all my keys and I have the BitLocker recovery keys. If there happens to be a way to avoid that in the likely event that they do *not* replace the MOBO, I'd like to do that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the recovery key, and then clear the TPM in BIOS.

On boot the computer will ask for the Bitlocker recovery key, and will not boot without it.

Send the computer off for service and your data will be safe.

Get the computer back and so long as the servicers did not reformat the drive you'll just plug the recovery key in when prompted and be OK.

HOWEVER, every servicer I'm aware of states they can and will reimage the computer if they deem it necessary.

So you should optimally remove the HDD from the computer before sending it unless your data is fully backed up.

**UPDATE for questions:**

Yes, after it is cleared, once the TPM is given the correct information it will be capable, once again, of helping the system automatically unlock the decrypted drive without requiring another full decryption/encryption.

There is a difference between **Suspending Bitlocker**, and **Disabling Bitlocker**:

Suspending Bitlocker allows changes to be made to the trust path from the hardware (BIOS/TPM) to the software (encrypted data) and tells the systems along that path to retain the trust relationship without requiring decryption and then re-encryption. You suspend Bitlocker when you need to update the BIOS, for instance. Disabling Bitlocker requires time to fully decrypt the drive.

Comment: Two things: (1) when the TPM is re-initialized, can I re-connect BitLocker to the TPM; and (2) in the future, there will be other things protected by TPM and I'd rather not re-connect them all (at present it's just two drives).

Comment: @iAdjunct - You can disable and enable BitLocker and store an entirely new key in the TPM.  Any modifications to the current confirmation will require the BitLocker recovery key anyways.

Comment: If I disable BitLocker, won't it decrypt the drive?

Comment: @iAdjunct - Yes;  You would immediately encrypt the drive.  Any event, if you clear the TPM, you will end up suspending BitLocker protection.  You should do research on what that will actually mean.

Comment: @iAdjunct please see updates to the answer.